# Using block buttons in a Bootstrap button group div

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a container with a button group. The buttons are centered, but their width needs to be 50% of its container, so that each button occupies one half of the container. I tried using `w-50` and `btn-block` but that just doesn't do the trick when using `btn-group`s.

This is my current code:

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">
            Back
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light">
            Next
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container text-center">
    <div class="btn-group w-100" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn w-50 btn-primary">
            Back
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn w-50 btn-primary">
            Next
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

You have to set the `btn-group` container to the full width you want it to use, then it will expand its buttons to the width you need. By default, `btn-group` has the property `display: inline-flex`, so it will not use the full width of the container.